# UWP InkCanvas restore strokes on OnNavigatedTo

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have an UWP app that uses an `InkCanvas` on one of it's pages. When the user leaves this page and then comes back to it, the `StrokeContainer` will still contain all strokes but the canvas will not show them so the canvas looks empty to the user.

I saw a lot of samples showing saving and loading of the strokes. I just want to achieve that the strokes are displayed all the time they are inside the container. I couldn't find any "Redraw"-mechanism or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean "the `StrokeContainer` will still contain all strokes"? How did you navigate between pages? Could you share the code you are using now?

Comment: @Scavenger I found a solution for this problem. To answer your question though: I navigate using NavigateTo as it is the default behavior. But when I use GoBack in NavigationService the StrokeContainer contains all strokes but the canvas will not redraw them automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to store the strokes in a local file before leaving the view and reloading them when you come back to the screen. First I add a new Extension-Class for making it more easy to handle the logic in the pages:

```
public static class InkCanvasExtensions
{
    public static async Task RestoreStrokesAsync(this InkCanvas inkCanvas, StorageFolder folder, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                using (var inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
                {
                    await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.LoadAsync(inputStream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<bool> StoreStrokesAsync(this InkCanvas inkCanvas, StorageFolder folder, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);
            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                {
                    await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(outputStream);
                    await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
            var status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);
            return status == FileUpdateStatus.Complete;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then inside of the page let's assume we have an `InkCanvas` named `myCanvas` and we will store everything in `ApplicationData.Current.SharedLocalFolder`:

```
public partial class Signature
{
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await myCanvas.RestoreStrokesAsync(ApplicationData.Current.SharedLocalFolder, "strokes.gif");
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await myCanvas.StoreStrokesAsync(ApplicationData.Current.SharedLocalFolder, "strokes.gif");
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }
}
```

This works pretty well in my case even if I still think that this approach is odd somehow.